Interpretation of prev task within context_switch() in Linux kernel scheduler code
I'm trying to understand the implementation of context switching in the Linux kernel (specifically in x86) and to that end I have a couple of questions.

Why is the switch_to() macro defined and invoked as shown below?

Is the value of prev in location (1) in the comments below the same as it is in location (2), or does the stack switch as part of switch_to() change it? If prev and next are stored in registers rsi and rdx, which don't appear to be saved in __switch_to_asm(), I would assume prev is the same in locations (1) and (2), but given the definition of the macro perhaps that's not the case?


#define switch_to(prev, next, last)                 \
do {                                    \
    ((last) = __switch_to_asm((prev), (next)));         \
} while (0)

From Linux kernel v5.8.6:
static __always_inline struct rq *
context_switch(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *prev,
           struct task_struct *next, struct rq_flags *rf)
{
    prepare_task_switch(rq, prev, next);

    /*
     * For paravirt, this is coupled with an exit in switch_to to
     * combine the page table reload and the switch backend into
     * one hypercall.
     */
    arch_start_context_switch(prev);

    /*
     * kernel -> kernel   lazy + transfer active
     *   user -> kernel   lazy + mmgrab() active
     *
     * kernel ->   user   switch + mmdrop() active
     *   user ->   user   switch
     */
    if (!next->mm) {                                // to kernel
        enter_lazy_tlb(prev->active_mm, next);

        next->active_mm = prev->active_mm;
        if (prev->mm)                           // from user
            mmgrab(prev->active_mm);
        else
            prev->active_mm = NULL;
    } else {                                        // to user
        membarrier_switch_mm(rq, prev->active_mm, next->mm);
        /*
         * sys_membarrier() requires an smp_mb() between setting
         * rq->curr / membarrier_switch_mm() and returning to userspace.
         *
         * The below provides this either through switch_mm(), or in
         * case 'prev->active_mm == next->mm' through
         * finish_task_switch()'s mmdrop().
         */
        switch_mm_irqs_off(prev->active_mm, next->mm, next);

        if (!prev->mm) {                        // from kernel
            /* will mmdrop() in finish_task_switch(). */
            rq->prev_mm = prev->active_mm;
            prev->active_mm = NULL;
        }
    }

    rq->clock_update_flags &= ~(RQCF_ACT_SKIP|RQCF_REQ_SKIP);

    prepare_lock_switch(rq, next, rf);

// LOCATION (1) 

    /* Here we just switch the register state and the stack. */
    switch_to(prev, next, prev);

// LOCATION (2) 

    barrier();

    return finish_task_switch(prev);
}


1) is easy to answer. Because it's very arch-dependent code. This is basically a "bridge" from arch-dependent to arch-independent code paths. We have a lot of these tricks in the kernel.

2) I assume that part of "why macro?" is exactly due to an update of the value of prev between two locations as you noticed.

Thanks @Oandriy. expanding the macro for x86 at the callsite, it's prev = __switch_to_asm(prev, next). The part that isn't clear to me is if prev is stored in a register, upon return from __switch_to_asm(..) which does callee saved register restore and stack switch, why would prev be different? It appears that the stack switch restores an older value of prev but I'm not clear why that's guaranteed in any way.

I believe the answer you are looking for is lurking in the calling convetions Linux uses: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.11.2/source/arch/x86/entry/calling.h#L14. It looks like rdi content is preserved in __switch_to_asm() and in __switch_to()

And looking again at your Q, seems you mistyped or really got wrong the parameters, they are in rdi, rsi and not rsi, rdx as you stated (order is important too!).

@Oandriy, yes the prev is in rdi but when the function context_switch() is invoked it's the second parameter, so should be in rsi and then later transferred over to rdi. Thanks for the link, but I don't see where rdi is being saved or restored as part of __switch_to_asm() or the function __switch_to() that it invokes. Answering that would resolve my question. IOW, through the function call sequence from context_switch() and below prev is only accessed via function argument (placed in a register).

How does it relevant that context_switch() has different parameters?

Next question: Why do you think rdi has to be restored? Is it mangled? I don’t see how…

Then __switch_to() is a C function. Can’t we simply look what it does?

@Oandriy  If I'm interpreting the code correctly prev is the return value from switch_to which is jumped to from __switch_to_asm. The return value of switch_to is based on its input argument, namely prev in rdi. However, the prev here should be different from the prev when context_switch() is invoked. The question is how is that "switch" accomplished? It's not obvious where that takes place from the code and would appreciate anyone familiar with that code to point to it.

Why should it be different? Where do you come this idea from?

because if it's not the macro makes zero sense. Anyways I've added a bounty to the question for folks familiar to help answer.


Why the switch_to() macro is defined and invoked as shown below (referenced below that)?

I can only assume this functionality is implemented as a macro because it is arch-dependent and it could possibly need more than a simple function call (like you see in x86). This is a common pattern for arch-specific code. You can see the different implementations of the macro here.

Is the value of prev in location (1) in the comment below the same as it is in location (2) or does the stack switch as part of switch_to() change it?

The stack switch does not really matter. The value of prev is not taken from nor saved to the stack. The new value of prev will simply be the return value of __switch_to_asm(), which is the return value of __switch_to() (since the former performs a tail call to the latter). Since __switch_to() returns the passed prev as is (see code), the final result is that the prev value is left unchanged.
This makes sense, you don't want the value of prev to change after the context is switched through switch_to(). If you schedule with prev=A next=B and previously B was switched away with prev=B next=C, you want B to resume with prev=A, not prev=B!

Yes, I should have looked the comments within finish_task_switch, which states ``` * finish_task_switch - clean up after a task-switch


@prev: the thread we just switched away from.


finish_task_switch must be called after the context switch, paired


with a prepare_task_switch call before the context switch.


finish_task_switch will reconcile locking set up by prepare_task_switch,


and do any other architecture-specific cleanup actions.```


Also suggests explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gOk3-X4y2U&t=930s is incorrect.

I am wondering what you told differently to my  comments...

@0andriy can't really make heads or tails of half the comments above, I tried to explain it more thoroughly so that it'd be clearer to OP (seems to have worked).
